# Handling Character Encoding Problems in Python using NLTK

Tags: python, unicode, character-encoding, nltk, codepages

I have downloaded and cleaned up a set of RSS feeds to be used as a Corpus with NLTK for testing classification. But when I run the Frequency Distribution many of the top results seem to be special characters:

`<FreqDist: '\x92': 494, '\x93': 300, '\x97': 159, ',\x94': 134, 'company': 124, '.\x94': 88, 'app': 84, 'Twitter': 82, 'people': 76, 'time': 73, ...>`

I tried the suggestion in the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345401/how-to-prevent-an-nltk-corpus-from-reading-extended-ascii-as-unicode) and initialized the corpus thusly (specifying the encoding):

```
my_corpus = CategorizedPlaintextCorpusReader('C:\\rss_feeds', r'.*/.*', cat_pattern=r'(.*)/.*',encoding='iso-8859-1')
print len(my_corpus.categories())
myfreq_dist = make_training_data(my_corpus)
```

but it only changed the results to:

`<FreqDist: u'\x92': 494, u'\x93': 300, u'\x97': 159, u',\x94': 134, u'company': 124, u'.\x94': 88, u'app': 84, u'Twitter': 82, u'people': 76, u'time': 73, ...>`

The python code file encoding is set:

`# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-`

For completeness, I use the following code to manipulate the Corpus Reader into training data:

```
def make_training_data(rdr):
    all_freq_dist = []
    #take union of all stopwords and punctuation marks
    punctuation = set(['.', '?', '!', ',', '$', ':', ';', '(',')','-',"`",'\'','"','>>','|','."',',"'])
    full_stop_set = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')) | punctuation
    for c in rdr.categories():
        all_category_words = []
        for f in rdr.fileids(c):
            #try to remove stop words and punctuation
            filtered_file_words = [w for w in rdr.words(fileids=[f]) if not w.lower() in full_stop_set]
            #add the words from each file to the list of words for the category
            all_category_words = all_category_words + filtered_file_words
        list_cat_fd = FreqDist(all_category_words), c
        print list_cat_fd
        all_freq_dist.append(list_cat_fd)
    return all_freq_dist
```

When I open the files themselves in Notepad++ it says that they are encoded in ANSI.

Ideally I would like to remove special characters and punctuation from the word list before generating the frequency distribution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: it might not be special characters, it might be accented characters. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3328995/how-to-remove-xe2-from-a-list

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution at the moment seems to be to add another set of characters (unicode_chars) to the full stop set to be eliminated before generating the frequency distribution:

```
punctuation = set(['.', '?', '!', ',', '$', ':', ';', '(',')','-',"`",'\'','"','>>','|','."',',"'])
other_words = set([line.strip() for line in codecs.open('stopwords.txt',encoding='utf8')])
unicode_chars = set([u',\u201d',u'\u2019',u'\u2014',u'\u201c',u'.\u201d',u'\ufffd', u',\ufffd', u'.\ufffd'])
full_stop_set = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')) | punctuation | other_words | unicode_chars
```

and then in the loop as before:

```
filtered_file_words = [w for w in rdr.words(fileids=[f]) if not w.lower() in full_stop_set]
```

It may not be the prettiest, but it keeps the strange characters from being considered in the frequency distribution.